# Will a TCP RST cause a host to drop the receive buffer?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Upon receiving a TCP RST packet, will the host drop all the remaining data in the receive buffer that has already been ACKed by the remote host but not read by the application process using the socket?

I'm wondering if it's dangerous to close a socket as soon as I'm not interested in what the other host has to say anymore (e.g. to conserver resources); e.g. if that could cause the other party to lose any data I've already sent, but he has not yet read.

Should RSTs generally be avoided and indicate a complete, bidirectional failure of communication, or are they a relatively safe way to unidirectionally force a connection teardown as in the example above?

Comment: I would guess what happens to the receive buffer when you send a RST packet (which essentially closes the connection) is *implementation dependent*

Comment: Fair point - I'd say I'm interested in the worst case, e.g. the data in the buffer WILL be dropped. Can that realistically occur with any hosts?

Comment: @Ixgr I doubt that the buffer would be flushed on a RST packet being received. But I don't know for sure if that is really the case. I'm guessing you'd need to try it. I would say that the buffer would be emptied in the sense that the receiving app would receive what's inside it.  Again, only speculation, don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application-level `close(2)` on a socket does not produce an `RST` but a `FIN` packet sent to the other side, which results in normal four-way connection tear-down. `RST`s are generated by the network stack in response to packets targeting not-existing TCP connection.

On the other hand, if you close the socket but the other side still has some data to write, its next [`send(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html) will result in `EPIPE`.

With all of the above in mind, you are much better off designing your own protocol on top of TCP that includes explicit "logout" or "disconnect" message.

Comment: It doesn't always produce a RST, but it definitely does when there is any unread data in the receive buffer of the socket. I'm now always draining the buffer (until either a timeout expires, or 0 is returned by read, which means that the other party has sent a FIN) before closing the socket to avoid that. My second link explains it in detail.

Comment: Yes, those are good well-known resources, great that you found them on your own. To quote from there: "... or if new data is received after CLOSE is called, its TCP SHOULD send a RST to show that data was lost." You sending data from the client after server closed its end of the connection. That's the problem. That's why you need a higher-level protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I've found some nice explanations of the topic, they indicate that data loss is quite possible in that case:
http://blog.olivierlanglois.net/index.php/2010/02/06/tcp_rst_flag_subtleties

http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable also gives some more information on the topic, and offers a solution that I've used in my code. So far, I've not seen any RSTs sent by my server application.

Comment: Your links are all about the situation where you close the connection while having unread data in the receive buffer and then a RST is sent to the other side. Yet the question was about the other side sending a RST (for whatever reason, doesn't matter) to you while you have still unread data in the buffer, which is a totally different situation.